# get text between span with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, lxml

I'm trying to scrape various sites using BeautifulSoup in Python.  Say I have the following `html` excerpt:

```
<div class="member_biography">
<h3>Biography</h3>
<span class="sub_heading">District:</span> AnyState - At Large<br/>
<span class="sub_heading">Political Highlights:</span> AnyTown City Council, 19XX-XX<br/>
<span class="sub_heading">Born:</span> June X, 19XX; AnyTown, Calif.<br/>
<span class="sub_heading">Residence:</span> Some Town<br/>
<span class="sub_heading">Religion:</span> Episcopalian<br/>
<span class="sub_heading">Family:</span> Wife, Some Name; two children<br/>
<span class="sub_heading">Education:</span> Some State College, A.A. 19XX; Some Other State College, B.A. 19XX<br/>
<span class="sub_heading">Elected:</span> 19XX<br/>
</div>
```

I need the results to be in the following format:

```
District:              AnyState - At Large
Political Highlights:  AnyTown City Council, 19XX-XX
Born:                  June X, 19XX; AnyTown, Calif.
Residence:             Some Town
Religion:              Episcopalian
Family:                Wife, Some Name; two children
Education:             Some State College, A.A. 19XX; Some Other State College, B.A. 19XX
Elected:               19XX
```

But, so far, I've only been able to achieve the following:

```
District:
Political Highlights:
Born:
Residence:
Religion:
Family:
Education:
Elected:
```

Using the following code:

```
import urllib.request
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def main(url):
    fp = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    site_bytearray = fp.read()
    fp.close()

    #bs_data = BeautifulSoup(site_str,features="html.parser")
    bs_data = BeautifulSoup(site_bytearray,'lxml')
    tmplist = bs_data.find_all('span',{'class':'sub_heading'})
    for item in tmplist:
        print(item.text)
    sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1])
```

In short, how do I extract `District` and `AnyState - At Large` from `<span class="sub_heading">District:</span> AnyState - At Large<br/>` and accumulate the results in a list for further processing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace your print command for:

Python 3.6+:

```
print(f'{item.text:<25} {item.next_sibling}')
```

Python 3 - 3.5:

```
print('{:<25} {}'.format(item.text, item.next_sibling))
```

Outputs:

```
District:                  AnyState - At Large
Political Highlights:      AnyTown City Council, 19XX-XX
Born:                      June X, 19XX; AnyTown, Calif.
Residence:                 Some Town
Religion:                  Episcopalian
Family:                    Wife, Some Name; two children
Education:                 Some State College, A.A. 19XX; Some Other State College, B.A. 19XX
Elected:                   19XX
```

Comment: Can you point me to something that explains this? For instance: what is {:<25} doing in the python3 example?

Comment: Nvm, I figured it out. Thanks

Comment: :<25 justify text left so its nice formatted as your requirements, remove it and you will se the difference

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `getText()` seems to always work for me.